# CONNECT ERROR: The 'local' channel is not installed. Please use the MAGE shell script to install the 'local' channel

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am kind of new to magento and php. I am getting the below error

[image: Error]

I found many solutions which says that in order to fix the above error we should do following steps:

```
chmod 777 mage
./mage mage-setup
```

when I try to run mage command in ubuntu I get

```
 No command 'mage' found, did you mean:
 Command 'mago' from package 'mago' (universe)
 Command 'make' from package 'make' (main)
 Command 'make' from package 'make-guile' (universe)
 Command 'mpage' from package 'mpage' (universe)
 Command 'mag' from package 'texlive-binaries' (main)
 Command 'page' from package 'tcllib' (universe)
 Command 'mame' from package 'mame' (multiverse)
 mage: command not found
```

Please help me in order to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

Please check if when creating the package extension file what value you entered in "channel" column under "Package Info" Section.

Solution:  The "channel" value must be "community".

You can check this value in "var/connect/your_package.tgz/package.xml" file.

This should look like:

community

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

If you dont want to follow above solution, please check below links for your issue  :

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Extensions/CONNECT-ERROR-The-community-channel-is-not-installed/td-p/78

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970939/magento-connect-error-the-community-channel-is-not-installed

https://www.ask-sheldon.com/magento-install-community-channel/